# Find string from path using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have path where i need to extract certain informations from.

```
string fullpath = @"D:\STACK\SalesNo6\Date20170101\Fileno16.txt";
```

I need to extract SalesNo6 into one variable and Date20170101 into another variable

```
string sales = Regex.Match(fullpath,"SalesNo[0-9]");

string date = Regex.Match(fullpath,"Date[0-9]");
```

But im not very good at regex so i cant spin my head around how to get the desired result. Can anybody advice me? Thanks

Comment: Why not split at \ and access the required info?

Comment: @CinCout Good question, havent thought about that. How would i know where to split from?

Comment: Tokenize the string at every backslash

Comment: Are the values always at the same location from the end? Just use `Path.GetDirectoryName` then.

Comment: 1rst about regex, you should [read](https://regexone.com/) a bit more about regex to learn about basic capture group and repetition

Comment: @CinCout What if the folder will be in incorrect position? Say, third or fourth?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, but the dates an no can of cause change but the path is always the same

Comment: @JohnyL He then needs to search for substrings in the resultant list

Comment: @DragandDrop Thanks for the link. I really need to upgrade my skills on regex.

Comment: `Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(fullpath))` and `Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(fullpath)))` will show the right values (in Windows).

Comment: @fubo Thanks i think that did the trick! You can leave an answer if it is.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ahh. Thats also a smart way to do it. Thanks i appreciate it alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the vaid patterns

```
string fullpath = @"D:\STACK\SalesNo6\Date20170101\Fileno16.txt";

string sales = Regex.Match(fullpath, @"SalesNo\d+").Value;
string date = Regex.Match(fullpath, @"Date\d{8}").Value;
```

- `\d+` for 1-n digits
- `\d{8}` for exact 8 digits which should match the date

---

`string.Split()` instead of RegEx

```
string fullpath = @"D:\STACK\SalesNo6\Date20170101\Fileno16.txt";

string sales = fullpath.Split('\\')[2];
string date = fullpath.Split('\\')[3];
```

Comment: If the path looks like `D:\STACK\PoorSalesNo16\SalesNo8\Date20170701\File.txt`, the extracted value will be a wrong one.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew are you sure that's a possible case?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for you comment ill take that into notice, but atm the business requirements wont change so the path will not change.

Comment: @plaidDK Then use my suggestion. Regex is usually not used in these scenarios when the subpaths are at the fixed locations in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to solve it

```
string fullpath = @"D:\STACK\SalesNo6\Date20170101\Fileno16.txt";
string date="";
string salesNo="";
// provide the pattern: \d mean digit; + means 1 or more of that, () put the inner value into a group
Regex reg=new Regex(@".*SalesNo(\d+).*Date(\d+).*");
// check if its a "valid" input
if(reg.IsMatch(fullpath)){
    // do matching
    var matches=reg.Matches(fullpath);
    //get the values from the match group
    salesNo=matches[0].Groups[1].Value;
    date=matches[0].Groups[2].Value;
}
```